# Extract comments of specific annotation of a PDF using iText

Tags: annotations, comments, itext, reply

using iText I am able to get a list of annotations of a PDF. It seems that even replies are annotations themselves.

Extracting them, I look at the contents of the PdfDictionary using this

```
Set<PdfName> keys = annot.getKeys();
for (PdfName key : keys) {
    System.out.println(key + "," + dictionary.get(key));
}
```

However, I cannot pinpoint which PdfName I need to use in order to identify replies belong to that certain annotation.

Comment: The PDF specification does not know *reply annotations.* Thus, you probably are talking about a proprietary use of some annotations. Thus, please share a sample to inspect to clarify what is meant.

Comment: Hi @mkl see http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-reply-annotation

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Oops, I see, and it indeed is already PDF specification stuff... Never seen it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the official documentation, more specifically at the answer to the example [How to add an "In Reply To" annotation?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-reply-annotation)

In this answer, I explain how to add an "In reply to" to an existing annotation. Let's open the resulting PDF and let's take a look inside:

[image]

As you can see, the annotation with the content "Hello PDF" is stored in an object with number 1. It is an annotation in reply to (`IRT`) the annotation with object number 2.

In answer to your question: you need to look at the key with value `PdfName.IRT` and this will give you the object number of the annotation to which the current number is a reply.

Comment: hi bruno, mkl. i managed to find out the annotation where pdfname.irt belongs to.

i store the pdfname.n value from pdfname.ap dictionary of the annitation

if the next annotation has pdfname.irt then i access the same pdfname.n from its pdfname.ap.

i then loop through my annotations to get the annotation that has the same value of pdfname.n

worked for me. thanks

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Could you please show how to set reference to the annotation using the object number obtained from the .IRT value?